# React Native Views on opposite sides

Tags: react-native

I would like to position two Views on opposite sides of each other within a parent View using React Native. The only way I've found to do this is by using a spacer View:

```
<View style={styles.parent}>
    <Text style={styles.left}> Left </Text>
    <View style={styles.spacer} />
    <Text style={styles.right}> Right </Text>
</View>
```

With styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parent: {
    flexDirection:'row',
  },
  spacer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Can I add styles to `left` and `right` replicate this, instead of using a spacer View? I found that using the props `marginRight` and `right` did not accomplish this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use space-between for justifyContent

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     parent: { 
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:'space-between'
     }, 
});
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for. Note that it's `justifyContent`